# How can i find UIActivityItemProvider action done

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi i am using UIActivityItemProvider to share my app data file to others. I used email, iMessage. So now i want to get the notification after send mail. How can i get back the email and iMessage delegate to finish.

Comment: What about `UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIActivityController` has a *completion handler*:

```
typedef void (^UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler)(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed);
```

Here's (quoting from the doc) what you'll get for the `completed` *boolean*:

> completed YES if the service was performed or NO if it was not. This
>   parameter is also set to NO when the user dismisses the view
>   controller without selecting a service.

Comment: It seems that the "completed" is NO if the share sheet is dismissed, YES otherwise. How do I know if the share action has been executed, but failed on the "target" app side, for whatever reason?